# Overflow background beyond window's width

Tags: html, css, flexbox, overflow

I have to design something like below:

- A parent container with 'n' childs that may very well go beyond the
  window's width and in that case page should scroll and not wrap to
  next line.
- The above container will be rendered multiple times below one
  another.
- The page should scroll as a whole, i.e. scroll should be at a wrapper
  (div with class `.overflow`) level and not at individual parent
  level.

Scroll horizontally in the snippet below to see the behavior.

```css
.overflow {
  overflow-x: auto;
}

.parent {
  background: #ccc;
  border: 4px solid blue;
  display: flex;
  margin: 10px 0;
}

.child {
  display: inline-flex;
  height: 50px;
  background: white;
  margin: 10px;
  flex: 1 0 300px;
  border: 2px solid red;
}
```

```html
<div class="overflow">
  <div class="parent">
    <div class="child">
      1
    </div>
    <div class="child">
      2
    </div>
    <div class="child">
      3
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="parent">
    <div class="child">
      1
    </div>
    <div class="child">
      2
    </div>
    <div class="child">
      3
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

The issue now is that the grey background on parent is not overflowing behind the children beyond the window's width.

How to achieve this (make `.parent` div background overflow for all its children) and possibly with retaining the `flex-box`?

Comment: Have you tried to use `:before` and `:after`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `inline-flex` for parent and replace `flex-basis` by `width`

```css
.overflow {
  overflow-x: auto;
}

.parent {
  background: #ccc;
  border: 4px solid blue;
  display: inline-flex;
  min-width:100%; /*To keep the block behavior*/
  box-sizing:border-box;
  margin: 10px 0;
}

.child {
  display: inline-flex;
  height: 50px;
  background: white;
  margin: 10px;
  width:300px;
  flex-shrink:0;
  flex-grow:1;
  border: 2px solid red;
}
```

```html
<div class="overflow">
  <div class="parent">
    <div class="child">
      1
    </div>
    <div class="child">
      2
    </div>
    <div class="child">
      3
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="parent">
    <div class="child">
      1
    </div>
    <div class="child">
      2
    </div>
    <div class="child">
      3
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Remove overflow div

Change your parent class css to

```
.parent {
  overflow-x: auto;
  background: #ccc;
  border: 4px solid blue;
  display: flex;
  margin: 10px 0;
}
```

Comment: "The page should scroll as a whole, i.e. scroll should be at a wrapper (div with class .overflow) level and not at individual parent level."